# GWT: date format changing itself in firefox when run on server

Tags: gwt

In my GWT application , i am displaying some dates , which are displaying in different format in chrome .. and different in Firefox ..

in chrome i am having this

```
                   9/7/2013 6:23:03 PM
```

in firefox its showing as

```
                   Saturday, September 07, 2013 6:23:03 PM
```

I am not changin format anywhere ...

I like the date to be same (as in chrome)

Note: it works fine and shows same format(as in chrome), but when i run on localhost it shows different format ..

any idea , what could be the solution

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [GWT DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) to show dates in a uniform manner. `DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a").format(YOUR_DATE);` will give you a `String`.